# Share web article with my Android Studio app

Tags: android, web, browser, hyperlink, share

I would like to develop an Android app that allows me to share a web article (from the browser on my phone) with my app. So that I can save the link of the article (or if possible even the whole text of the article) in my app. The target is that the user then can just click on the link at a later point in time and reopen the article in the browser again.

Unfortunately, I only find confusing information on the internet and no real concrete example. Can anyone help me, please? :(

Comment: "Just like it is possible with whatapp:" -- rather than drawing comparisons to other apps that may change over time, please edit your question and explain in detail what you are looking to accomplish. My guess is that you are referring to [this](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive), but it is difficult to tell from your question.

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous. Do you want to show the article inside your app? Do you want to just share the link in the app and then click the link and open it in a browser? How do you intend to share the article from the browser?

Comment: @SaadWaseem For a start I would like to share the link in the app and save it there, so that the user can click on it later an open it in the browser again. If it is possible to even save the whole article in the app I would be also interested in implementing this in a next step, but first of all saving the link is important.

Comment: @CommonsWare As explained in the comment above I would like to simply save the browser link and was therefore looking for a concrete example where this is implemented with a browser like chrome for example.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are looking to create an app to receive a link from a browser, where the user uses a share menu option (or toolbar button or whatever) in the browser.

Generally speaking, to do that, you need to implement an `Activity` that supports the `ACTION_SEND` protocol. There are two main pieces to that.

First, you will need to add an `<intent-filter>` to the `<activity>` in your manifest, advertising that you support `ACTION_SEND` for plain text:

```xml
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
      </intent-filter>
```

Then, in your activity, you can get the `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` and get the URL. Roughly speaking, that would be:

```kotlin
  private fun saveBookmark(intent: Intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND == intent.action) {
      val pageUrl = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)
        ?: intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)

      if (pageUrl != null && Uri.parse(pageUrl).scheme!!.startsWith("http")) {
        // TODO something with the URL
      } else {
        // TODO you did not get a URL, so show an error or something
      }
    }
  }
```

You would call `saveBookmark()` from two places:

- `onCreate()`, passing in the value of `getIntent()`
- `onNewIntent()`, passing in the `Intent` that you get as a parameter to `onNewIntent()`

You can learn more about this in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive).

Comment: thanks a lot, that's the kind of answer I was hoping for. I followed the steps and my app now shows up as an option when I press the share button in the browser. Then my app opens, but the incoming intent is not of type Intent.ACTION_SEND instead Intent.ACTION_MAIN. So I don't get any text or url sent. Do you know what could be the reason for this?

Comment: @Sophia282: Make sure that you are overriding `onNewIntent()` and using the `Intent` from there, if you get one. `onCreate()` gets called when your activity is created, and  `getIntent()` will return the `Intent` used to create the activity. If the activity was already running (e.g., from the IDE, from the launcher), then `getIntent()` will be the `ACTION_MAIN` `Intent`. However, if the activity is already running and you share from another app, that may be triggering `onNewIntent()`, and the `Intent` object that you get as a parameter will be the `ACTION_SEND` one.

Comment: One last question: when I click on share, the url is sent to me and when I highlight a paragraph in the article, for example, this highlighted text + the url is sent to my app. Is there also a way to send the entire text of an article directly via share to my app without having to mark everything first in the browser?

Comment: @Sophia282: If that is an option, it would be up to the browser. You cannot force browser developers to do anything. There are many Web browsers for Android. "when I highlight a paragraph in the article, for example, this highlighted text + the url is sent to my app" -- it does for whatever browser you are testing. This is not necessarily the case for every browser.

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for is a backend system for your application. You should check [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/). Use Firebase Authentication for user login, and Firebase Firestore/Realtime Database for syncing the links.

You will obviously need a web-based client to share the links to the app from the browser.

Comment: I already have set up Firebase Real Time Database in my app to store there some info about the user. 
Do you have an advice where I can look an example for the second step?

Comment: For the second step, which is sending a link from the browser to the app, you need to create a website, connect it with firebase, make the user log in, and then create a text field and button that stores the link in the real-time database of the user. Syncing it in the app should be easier then.